# Століття чи сторіччя?

Tags: вживання-слів

Чому слово сторіччя вживається рідше, ніж століття? Адже це проміжок часу в сто років, тому було б логічніше називати його саме сторіччям.

Comment: Запитання **чому**, але затверӝена відповідь про _існування слів_, ех. Але так, _сторіччя_ лӧґічніше, останнім часом ӧго зустрічаю частіше.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

СУМ подає визначення цих слів так:

> ***СТОРІ́ЧЧЯ***, я, сер.
>
> 1. Час, період тривалістю сто років; століття, вік. В вісімнадцятім сторіччі, Як вікно в заморський світ, Цар Петро в цім межиріччі Місто звів (Іван Нехода, Ми живемо.., 1960, 120); [Чубатенко:] Народ наш творить суд над російськими поміщиками, що сторіччя тримали наші кращі землі (Олександр Корнійчук, I, 1955, 164); Сторіччями вірменський народ оспівував безсмертну силу води (Комуніст України, 3, 1967, 25).
> 2. Річниця, роковини чого-небудь, що відбулося або почало існувати сто років тому. Не сторіччя з дня його [Т. Шевченка] смерті ми будемо відзначати, а його безсмертя, безсмертя правди, безсмертя народу! (Максим Рильський, Веч. розмови, 1964, 31); Сторіччя з дня заснування І Інтернаціоналу — свято всього світового робітничого і комуністичного руху (Комуніст України, 9, 1964, 10).
>
> ***СТОЛІ́ТТЯ***, я, сер. Те саме, що сторіччя. Століття люди б'ються, Щоб воленьки здобуть!.. (Леся Українка, I, 1951, 36); Минуть століття, а ім'я великого Леніна, його діла, його неповторний образ житимуть у пам'яті народів усього світу (Комуніст України, 4, 1967, 10); За це от біле молоко гумове Століттями точилася війна (Максим Рильський, III, 1961, 295); Посадовила я тополю в день народження Кобзаря, саме на століття (Юрій Яновський, I, 1954, 13).

**Отже ці слова є синонімами.**
Також слово [*літа*](http://sum.in.ua/s/lita) є цілком літературним і може вживатись, як певний період часу у житті суспільства. Тому *сто років* і *сто літ* — це тотожні поняття і можуть вживатись однаково часто, так як *століття* і *сторіччя*.